# xmlhttprequest.getAllResponseHeaders() IE different than Chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, response-headers

Am trying to get a response header after sending an URL , it works with chrome and firefox but it doesn't work with internet explorer:
the response header of chrome and firefox :

```
auth Bearer eyJXdjhgfdjhdjgfdjfbjfdhf...
```

but using the same methode , in IE i get this result :

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: fr-FR
```

My code :

```
var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
var url="***"
xhr.open("GET", url ,true);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.send();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log('status=',this.status);
        if (this.status == 200) {
            console.log('all header=',xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
            var json = xhr.getResponseHeader("auth");
            sessionStorage.setItem('Auth', json)
                    }
                  };
                }
```

can you help me on this topic please ?

Comment: any solutions please ?

Comment: Is `auth Bearer ...` the complete response header in Chrome? It seems that it's the `auth` of the response header. [A complete response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getAllResponseHeaders#return_value) should be like the result in IE. I tested your code and it can log the complete response headers in IE and Chrome and the results are the same. The format is like IE result what you showing in the thread.

Comment: @YuZhou yes the response auth bearer... is a json web token in chrome and it's all what i need,On the other hand on the internet explorer the answer is so different usin the same methode.

Comment: So what you showing the result in IE is the `auth` you get in IE? In your code, you `console.log('all header=',xhr.getAllResponseHeaders())`, what're the results in IE and Chrome? Please show us so that we can compare what's the difference. Besides, is there any error in console in IE?